# solspace user - Ajax submit form

Tags: solspace-user, ajax, registration

I was having a heck of a time trying to get the solspace user module to submit my form via ajax.  I was trying to use the default EE method found here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/examples.html#ajax-driven-entry-form

It just seemed the user module was ignoring the json="yes" and any jquery that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

By searching some other solspace forum product questions I found that **ajax="yes"** was needed.  Once I added that to the user {exp:user:register} tag my jquery worked perfect.

Not sure why this isn't in the solspace user documentation.  Just thought I'd post it for others having issues with ajax and user.